# How do I change the ASP.NET Membership Provider in code?

Tags: asp.net

How do I change the ASP.NET Membership Provider in code? I need to override it for unit testing.

Comment: Perhaps you can use multiple Membership Provider, simply add the another provider <membership> section of the application’s web.config

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can't do it in a good way, as [`Membership.Provider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.provider(v=vs.110).aspx) hasn't setter, but you can always change it by reflection. `Membership` class has such field that stores current Membership provider:

```
public static class Membership
{
   private static MembershipProvider s_Provider;
```

So if you set it to custom value by reflection, then ASP.Net controls will use your new provider.

Originally this property initialized only once and you can't change normally.

Other way might be having different config for unit tests that will point to different Membership provider in membership section, but don't know will it work for Membership provider or not.